# c# wcf service accept Int8Array from javascript as parameter

Tags: javascript, c#, wcf

I've got an Int8Array in javascript that I'm trying to pass to a WCF Service.  Ultimately I'll convert the Int8Array to a byte array and save the data (photos) into a database.  The problem I'm having is I cant get the WCF Service to accept the Int8Array.  The Int8Array is being created from a FileReader object in javascript.

Javascript code to create Int8Array

```
 var reader = new FileReader();
//display photo on page
reader.onload = function (e) {
dojo.byId('img1').src = reader.result;
var arrayBuffer = reader.result;
var u = new Int8Array(arrayBuffer);
FormSawpaDB.PhotoSave(u, lang.hitch(me.PhotoSaveConfirm));//me is the page
}

// Read in the image file as a data URL
reader.readAsArrayBuffer(f);
```

Javascript call to WCF Service:

```
PhotoSave: function (d, callback) {
//callback("its been hit", "ok")
    xhr.post({//send data
        url: this.dataServiceUrl + "/PhotoSave",
        postData: dojo.toJson(d),
        contentType: "application/json",
        handleAs: "json",
        load: function (result) {
            callback(result, "ok");

        },
        error: function (err) {
            callback(null, "Error -- photo not inserted.");
        }

    });
}
```

WCF Service Method:

```
public String PhotoSave(SByte[] u)
        {
            return "ok";
        }
```

WCF Service Template:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
    UriTemplate = "PhotoSave")]
String PhotoSave(SByte[] u);
```

I'm getting a 404 Not able to load error.  I know I can communicate with service because I can send a string or int fine, but this IntArray is giving me problems.  Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

I think I've got the web config set up ok:

```
<services>
          <service name="WatershedSignsService.SignService" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
              <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WatershedSignsService.ISignService" behaviorConfiguration="web"/>
          </service>
      </services>
      <bindings>
          <webHttpBinding>
              <binding name="webHttpBindingDev" maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000" maxBufferSize="20000000" maxBufferPoolSize="20000000">
                  <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
              </binding>
          </webHttpBinding>
      </bindings>
```

Thanks

Pete

Comment: I'm trying to now pass a blob from javascript to a Stream object in the c# wcf service -- getting a 500 error.

Comment: trying int16[] array -- it hits the wcf service but the array is empty when it gets to the service

Comment: by encoding the int16[] array to base64 string in javascript I can pass the data to a string parameter in the wcf service.

Comment: found a method to post stream from javascript to wcf here:

https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/757991/File-Upload-using-WCF-REST-API-and-JavaScript